# Neo4j match Relationship parameters satisfying a certain schema

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using cypher, is there any way to match a path where the relationships satisfy a certain input schema generically?

I know I can do something like

```
parameters: {
    "age": 20
}

MATCH (n)-[r:MY_RELATION]-() WHERE $age>18 AND $age<24 ...
```

when i want to match only relations satisfying the schema `{ "type": "integer", "minimum": 19, "maximum": 23 }`.

But then i have to specify the min and max range within the relationship. What if I want to match strings against a schema, or even more complex types like address with subparameters etc.?

Is there a generic way to do it?

**edit:**
I'll try and state the question more clearly. What I want is a graph and a  (parameterized) query to traverse that graph, such that:

- i get all the nodes in the traversal
- the relationships in the graph pose certain constraints on the query parameters (like minimum on an integer)
- the traversal only follows edges where the constraint is met
- i need to make constraints on integers, like min/max, but as well on strings, like pattern, etc.

**edit 2:**
What I want may not even be possible.
I want all of the information about the constraint to reside in the edge, including the parameter to test against. So I would want something along the lines of

```
parameters: { "age": 20, "location": "A" }
MATCH (n)-[r]-()
WHERE r.testtype='integer' AND getParameterByName(r.testparamname) < r.max
OR r.testtype='string' AND getParameterByName(r.testparamname)=r.allowedStringValue
```

Of course, as can be read in the [neo4j documentation about parameter functionality](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/) it should not be possible to dynamically load the parameter via a name that resides in the DB.

There may yet be some workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UPDATED]

### Original answer:

Your question is not stated very clearly, but I'll try to answer anyway.

I think something like this is what you want:

```
parameters: {
  "minimum": 19,
  "maximum": 23
}

MATCH (n)-[r:MY_RELATION]-() WHERE $maximum >= r.age >= $minimum
...
```

There is no need to specify a "type" parameter. Just make sure your parameter values are of the appropriate type.

### New answer (based on updated question):

Suppose the parameters are specified this way (where `test` indicates the type of test):

```
parameters: {
  "age": 20,
  "test": "age_range"
}
```

Then you could do this (where `r` would contain the properties `test`, `min`, and `max`):

```
MATCH (n)-[r:MY_RELATION]-(m)
WHERE r.test = $test AND r.min <= $age <= r.max
RETURN n, r, m;
```

Or, if you do not need all the relationships to be of the same type, this should also work and may be easier to visualize (where `r` would be of, say, type "age_range", and contain the properties  `min` and `max`):

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-(m)
WHERE TYPE(r) = $test AND r.min <= $age <= r.max
RETURN n, r, m;
```

To help you decide which approach to use, you should [profile](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) the two approaches with your code and some actual data to see which is faster for you.

### Even Newer answer (based on edit 2 in question)

The following parameter and query should do what you want. Square brackets can be used to dyamically specify the name of a property.

```
parameters: {
  "data": {
    "age": 20,
    "location": "A"
  }
}

MATCH (n)-[r]-()
WHERE r.testtype='integer' AND $data[r.testparamname] < r.max
OR r.testtype='string' AND $data[r.testparamname]=r.allowedStringValue
...
```

Comment: Please see my edit in the original question. In particular, I need the constraints to reside in the relationships of the graph, not in the parameters (in your example, min/max are in the parameters). the parameters are supposed to be the data fulfilling the constraints

Comment: Thank you for the update. Still, it's not quite generic enough. Please see the updated question

Answer (score 0):

Does this solution meet your requirements?

Considering the following small sample data set

```
MERGE (p1:Person {name: 'P 01'})
MERGE (p2:Person {name: 'P 02'})
MERGE (p3:Person {name: 'P 03'})
MERGE (p1)-[:MY_RELATION { minimum: 19, maximum: 23 }]->(p2)
MERGE (p2)-[:MY_RELATION { minimum: 19, maximum: 20 }]->(p3)
```

This query will only return the nodes and relationship where the supplied parameter fits the relationship constraints (e.g. $age = 21 should only return a single row). It is basically the inverse of @cybersam's proposal.

```
MATCH (s:Person)-[r:MY_RELATION]->(e:Person)
WHERE r.minimum <= $age <= r.maximum
RETURN *
```